# How to Change Label Name Attribute in simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am creating a ratings form for a number of polymorphic models, Trip and Service, both of which expose the Rateable mixin, which brings in an association `has_many :ratings`.  To submit a single form, I conglomerate both polymorphic models into a proxy, then iterate over the proxy to create the form with simple_fields_for.

Because the forms are for Rating objects on Rateable obj, simple_form created a series of fields, but the names are all "ratings[value]", "ratings[comments]" etc.  To fix this, I used the `index` parameter I found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), which fixed the name issue, as shown below.  The labels didn't change as well, though, and I don't know how to tell SimpleForm to use the `index` param to change the label's `for` attribute.

```
RatingsProxy.rb
  attr_reader :rateables # A simple array of different types of Models
end

module Rateable
  has_many :ratings, as: :rateable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings
end

= simple_form_for @ratings_proxy do |f|
  - @ratings_proxy.rateables.each do |rateable|
    = simple_fields_for :ratings, rateable.ratings.build, index: rateable.class.name do |ratings_form|
      = ratings_form.input :value, as: :radio_buttons
        = ratings_form.input :comments
```

Now, my HTML for the inputs looks like this:

```
<!-- Created by one rateable model, Trip.  Note the name attribute on the label vs. input -->
<label for="ratings_Trip_value_5" name="ratings[value]">
  <input class="radio_buttons required" id="ratings_Trip_value_5" name="ratings[Trip][value]" type="radio" value="5">
  5
</label>
...
<!-- Created by a different rateable model, Service -->
<label for="ratings_value_5" name="ratings[value]">
  <input class="radio_buttons required" id="ratings_Service_value_5" name="ratings[Service][value]" type="radio" value="5">
  5
</label>
```

I added the `index` param on the simple_fields_for expecting it to update labels as well as inputs, but it doesn't seem to have done so.  **How do I change where the label points, so that it points at the inputs with the new name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by replacing `ratings_form.input :value, as: :radio_buttons` with `ratings_form.collection_radio_buttons`

Comment: As a follow up, I never found any method which controls the label's `for` attribute in simpleform